# Nginx rewriting a url with url ars for a specific script without having the .js extention to the map

Tags: nginx, rewrite

My webpage dynamically does the following request:

> http://example.com/f1/script?param1=1&param2=2&...&paramn=n

And I want to my nginx server when is visited to load a file named `script.js`

Therefore I did:

```
location ~^/f1/script?.* {
 rewrite ^/f1/script?.* /f1/script.js;
}
```

But the browser fails to receive it.

Do you know how to make my browser to successfully receive the file?

## Edit 1

I tried to do the following:

```
location ~^/f1/ {
    try_files $uri $uri.js;
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $uri.js;
}
```

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970674/remove-php-file-extension-with-nginx-php-fpm#17475222 but still no light in my path

Answer (score 0):

nginx does not match query arguments in `location` or `rewrite` directives.

Therefore you need to use:

```
location /f1/script {
    try_files $uri $uri.js;
}
```

There could be problems with content type header over here, that is, the browser refuses to run the script because its content type is invalid. In that case one needs to find a way to add the proper content type header.

Easier approach would be to simply use `script.js` in the URL.